# picking 8 cards from a usual deck of 52 playing cards.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

choose 8 cards from a usual deck of 52 playing cards.how many ways can this be done

(4) All 8 cards that have values between 2 and 8 inclusive.
(5) All 8 cards and they all have different values (where Jacks are different from Queens).

i already done 3 questions but i really have no idea how to do these two, any hint?

Comment: For (4) what is wrong with supposing the deck is reduced to the $20$ cards with values $2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$8$ before even selecting the $8$ cards?

Comment: For (5) you might select the values first, then associate a suit to each value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4. Let us assume: 52 card deck, shuffled 7 times so now random, one player dealt a total of 8 cards. There are four "$2s$", four "$3s$", four "$4s$", four "$5s$", four "$6s$", four "$7s$", and four "$8s$" - call these 28 cards successes. There remain 24 other cards, call them failures. The probability of being dealt 8 cards all of which are between 2 and 8, inclusive, would be:

$\dfrac{\binom{28}{8}\binom{24}{0}}{\binom{52}{8}}$ = $\dfrac{3,108,105*1}{752,538,150} = 0.00413016.$

Generalize for 5.

Does this reply help?